# unable to import normalize_corpus python 3

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, normalization

I am working on some NLP task, trying to import normalize_corpus from the normalization module.

I am getting the below error.

```
 from normalization import normalize_corpus
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-13-5919bba55473> in <module>()
    ----> 1 from normalization import normalize_corpus

    ImportError: cannot import name 'normalize_corpus'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normalization module you have installed (probably https://pypi.org/project/normalization/) does not correspond to the code you are trying to run (possibly from "Text Analytics with Python").

Uninstall the normalization module and track down the code from the book. (A place to start: https://github.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python)

Comment: The **github link** you provided is dead, would be great if you could update it with the full answer, instead of the link - since it can be dead anytime

Comment: Please check this link: https://github.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python/blob/b4f6cefc9dd96e2a3e74e01bda391019bd7fb053/Old-First-Edition/Ch05_Text_Summarization/normalization.py

Answer (score 1):

For whoever lands here because you are reading "Text analytics with Python". [The author of the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484232062) is referring to a custom script they built and is hosted in the first edition - chapter 4 or 5 -

https://github.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python/blob/master/Chapter-4/normalization.py

https://github.com/dipanjanS/text-analytics-with-python/blob/b4f6cefc9dd96e2a3e74e01bda391019bd7fb053/Old-First-Edition/Ch05_Text_Summarization/normalization.py